# Heroku - Timeout on cURL (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, heroku, timeout

I'm trying to create a API proxy for my application but I'm getting some strange timeout erros on Heroku.

The said the following:

```
2012-12-10T12:49:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/api/v1/users/me host=host.herokuapp.com fwd=174.129.79.221 dyno=web.1 queue= wait= connect= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

The code is something like the following:

```
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'AppProxy/1.0');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $authorization,
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($request);
echo curl_errno($request) . "<br />";
echo curl_error($request) . "<br />";
echo $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . "<br />";
curl_close($request);
echo $response . "<br />";
```

There's something wrong or I'm missing something on the code to get this working?
Anyone had the same issue on Heroku?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you provide more details about *API proxy* and the exact difference between the normal API usage.

Comment: @William Lepinski

Did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm hitting this same error when trying to cURL a local PHP endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a timeout on your cUrl request like so

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
```

How long does it take to wget the same resource from the box it is running on?

Also code 503 is a Service Unavailable error. Can you open the resource in your browser?

Comment: The same request, made on Postman for example, took only 180ms.

Comment: Maybe the heroku box can't reach the other box. If you can ssh into the heroku box then try some diagnostics from there

Comment: The other box in this case is the same box. I'm only wrapping the request with some sensitive data that can't be on the client-side. Works like a proxy, but the request is sent along with the APIKey of the logged user (yes, I'm doing a single-page JS app). Sounds like Heroku has some security policies for requests made on the server-side using CURL.